# How to properly use absolute path with typescript and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsconfig, absolute-path

I know, many people has this question, I already tried all those options and still having issues, so let's see my case:

I want to import my functions like this:

```js
import { generateOTP, sendOTP } from 'helpers';
```

instead of:

```js
import { generateOTP, sendOTP } from '../../helpers';
```

the `helpers/` folder has inside an index with the export of other files

```js
export * from './model-helpers';
export * from './routes-helpers';
export * from './controllers-helpers';
export * from './general-use';
```

In VSCode, already have the import as I want:

```js
import { generateOTP, sendOTP } from 'helpers';
```

and when I clicked in the functions, **I can go directly to it! vscode doesn't shows/throws any error, I can navigate to the function**

***BUT the console shows me this error:***

```bash
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/index.ts`
Error: Cannot find module 'helpers'
Require stack:
- /Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/controllers/Auth.controller.ts
- /Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/controllers/index.ts
- /Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/routes/order.routes.ts
- /Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/routes/index.ts
- /Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/models/Server.ts
- /Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/node_modules/.pnpm/@cspotcode+source-map-support@0.8.1/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/controllers/Auth.controller.ts:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.9.1_@types+node@18.15.13_typescript@5.0.4/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/node_modules/.pnpm/ts-node@10.9.1_@types+node@18.15.13_typescript@5.0.4/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/controllers/Auth.controller.ts',
    '/Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/controllers/index.ts',
    '/Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/routes/order.routes.ts',
    '/Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/routes/index.ts',
    '/Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/models/Server.ts',
    '/Users/israelsantiago/Downloads/Code/meraki-projects/hocalis-order-system/api/src/index.ts'
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

IDK what to do :(

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "allowJs": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "alwaysStrict": true,
      "baseUrl": "./src",            
      "esModuleInterop": true,       
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "importHelpers": true,
      "module": "nodenext",
      "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "noImplicitAny": false,        
      "noImplicitReturns": false,
      "noImplicitThis": false,
      "noUnusedLocals": false,
      "noUnusedParameters": false,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "paths": {
        "/*": ["./src/*", "./src"],
      },
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "strict": true,                
      "strictNullChecks": false,
      "target": "esnext",
      "types": ["node", "vitest", "express"],
      "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*", "./__tests__/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  }
```

this is my .eslintrc.json (just in case):

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ],
        // "sort-imports": ["error", {
        //     "ignoreCase": false,
        //     "ignoreDeclarationSort": false,
        //     "ignoreMemberSort": false,
        //     "memberSyntaxSortOrder": ["single", "all", "multiple", "none"],
        //     "allowSeparatedGroups": true
        // }],
        "sort-vars": ["error", { "ignoreCase": true }]
    }
}
```

package.json (just in case):

```json
{
  "name": "hocalis_order_system_api",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "commit": "pnpm run lint:fix && pnpm run test && git add . && pnpm run cz && git push",
    "cz": "npx cz-customizable",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts",
    "lint:fix": "pnpm run lint --fix",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .ts",
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "test:watch": "vitest --reporter verbose",
    "test": "vitest --run"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "1.20.2",
    "cloudinary": "1.36.1",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "date-fns": "2.29.3",
    "dotenv": "16.0.3",
    "express": "4.18.2",
    "express-session": "1.17.3",
    "express-validator": "7.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.12.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "3.2.3",
    "node-mailjet": "^6.0.4",
    "otp-generator": "^4.0.1",
    "sequelize": "6.31.0",
    "short-uuid": "^4.2.2",
    "twilio": "^4.16.0",
    "uuid": "9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/recommended": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "2.4.2",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "@types/cors": "2.8.13",
    "@types/express": "4.17.17",
    "@types/express-session": "1.17.7",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "9.0.1",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.5",
    "@types/node": "18.15.13",
    "@types/sequelize": "4.28.14",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@types/uuid": "9.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.59.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.0",
    "cz-customizable": "7.0.0",
    "eslint": "8.39.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "tslint": "6.1.3",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "vitest": "^0.34.3",
    "winston": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

And finally this is how my project folder structure looks like:
[image]

doesn anyone has an idea about what's going on?

Comment: NodeJS doesn't support this by default. TypeScript provides the baseUrl and paths options to model bundlers and loaders such as SystemJS, RequireJS, and Webpack, which do support this behavior via configuration.

Comment: "I want to import my functions like this" why? Is typing the extra 6 characters going to give you carpal tunnel or something? How much work do you expect to happen in the background while your tools scan various directories on your file systems? What happens when it's ambiguous because you've got `/foo/helpers/index.ts` and `/bar/helpers/index.ts` in your project and you try to import an unqualified `helpers` in some file in some other directory `/baz`?

Comment: that's why I want to point directly to `src/` so any file I want, will start searching from `src/`, plus.. this is just one example, my project has many files/folders and some of them need to to `import {} from '../../../../'` specially the tests ones... so answering your question regarding the `/baz` example, there wouldn't be a problem at all, if `/baz` is directly under `src/`, then I will do `bar/helpers/index.ts` that's it, I don't see any problem... just can't configure it

Answer (score 1):

You can update your [tsconfig paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) to include the `helpers` reference (assuming `src/helpers`):

```
"paths": {
  "/*": ["./src/*", "./src"],
  "helpers*": ["./src/helpers/*", "./src/helpers/index"],
},
```

Then you can import using `import {} from 'helpers'`

If you want to import any folder relative to `src`, add

```
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths" {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
  }
```

And import using `import {} from 'src/helpers'` or `'src/[subfolder]'`

Comment: But is there any way I can directly access through src to any folder? Or do I need to add a path for every single folder inside src/?

Comment: Yes, you can add `"src/*": ["./src/*", "./src"],` and then import using `import {} from 'src/helpers'` too

Comment: it didn't work, I got this error
`node@18.15.13_typescript@5.0.4/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/controllers/Auth.controller.ts:5:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/helpers' or its corresponding type declarations.

5 import { generateOTP, sendOTP } from 'src/helpers';

`

Comment: is the folder structure `src/helpers/index.ts`?

Comment: yes, that's the structure

Comment: Edited the answer to include answer to follow up

Answer (score -1):

You can remove

```
      "paths": {
        "/*": ["./src/*", "./src"],
      },
```

or set baseUrl to `'.'` and not `'./src'`

Comment: One or another? Let me try

Comment: It is "or" not and

Comment: didn't work at all

Comment: Which option did you try?